# JSON Response coming null secondtime in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, json, response

In `connectionDidFinishLaunching` method ,

I am writing this ,

in `ViewWillAppear`

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

and in

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

i am getting data ...which i am putting in the string ...

```
NSString *responsestring=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"responsestring is %@",responsestring);
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [responsestring JSONValue];
MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
```

when Calling webservice first time --- > I get the right data in the dictionary .

when I go to the other view controller and come back at same place ---> `viewWillAppear` is getting called . in string the correct value is coming up .. request url in `ViewWillAppear` is also same .. but after `self.dict= [responsestring JSONValue];` I am getting this time null ..

how is this possible?

Comment: what are you getting in dictionary in 2nd time ???

Comment: @InderKumarRathore .. I am getting null ... I am getting correct response in String but in Dictionary it is null

Comment: can you give the json response for both requests?

Comment: @Inder Kumar Rathore .. I am afraid they are too huge to paste here :(

Comment: but both the time I am doing same request

Comment: can you post more describing your issue there?

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are not retaining the dictionary. If you want to use that dictionary in future, you should retain it.

Comment: @apurva ... Thanks ... but where should I retain it?